# Calling a method with an event handler

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Why, if I put a "normal" call to the method `button1Click()` in the `bind` call, does my program not even start? By removing the parenthesis the problem is solved.
I'm using this program as reference: [Thinking in Tkinter](http://www.ferg.org/thinking_in_tkinter/tt060_py.txt)

Also, why should I add the `event` argument to my `button1Click()` method?

```
from Tkinter import *
class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.myParent = parent 
        self.myContainer1 = Frame(parent)
        self.myContainer1.pack()

        self.button1 = Button(self.myContainer1)
        self.button1.configure(text="OK", background= "green")
        self.button1.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.button1.bind("<Button-1>", self.button1Click) # <--- no () !

    def button1Click(self, event):
        self.button2 = Button(self.myContainer1, text="lol")
        self.button2.bind("<Button-1>", self.button1Click)
        self.button2.pack()

root = Tk()
myapp = MyApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind()` expects something that is callable and that expects an argument.

If you pass `self.button1Click()`,  you effectively pass it `None`, because that is what is returned by this call.

As the call is to be performed by the clickable object, you are not supposed to call it yourself.

So, next step: You pass it `self.button1Click`, and you clock the button. Then the given "thing" is tried to be called with an event object as argument, but that fails, because the method is not prepared for that.

So you have 2 options:

- Either you modify the method so it can be called with an `event` object, such as `def button1Click(self, event):`,
- or you wrap it in a lambda call: `lambda event: self.button1Click()`.

In the latter case, you give the `bind()` method a callable which accepts exactly one argument, and does the call as wanted at the time of calling (thus the `()`).

Answer (score 1):

You can call the method `button1Click` "normally" using `lambda`. What might be happening right now is that it would be getting called anyhow.

For ex: `command=lambda:self.button1Click()`

You can pass more arguments if you like by putting them in the parenthesis.

You need to use the `event` argument because whenever you bind a method you are passing `event` object too automatically. In your case,its two arguments-the event object & `self`.

Comment: Why do I have to use lambda?

Comment: refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5771787/2276527) for its detailed explaination

Comment: You don't need to use a lambda (although it's often useful to do so)

Comment: wouldn't i be needing to use it if i want to send some argument or even empty `()`. Either `lambda` or any other intermediate function?